# Paper JS Subtract Paths Result Empty

Tags: paperjs

I am new to PaperJs and i am trying to subtract 2 SVG paths.

The html contains two svgs, svg1 and svg2 both of which contain a path.

```
function SVGPath(elem){
    var a = new paper.Path(paper.project.importSVG(elem));
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return a;
}

window.onload = function() {
    paper.setup('canvas');

    var svg1 = document.getElementById('svg1')
    var path1 = SVGPath(svg1);
    path1.fillColor = "red"
    path1.position = new paper.Point(0, 0);


    var svg2 = document.getElementById('svg2')
    var path2 = SVGPath(svg2);
  path2.fillColor = 'green'
    path2.position = new paper.Point(0, 0);

    var result = path1.subtract(path2)
    result.position = new paper.Point(10,10)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/820c3sw4/4/

I am trying to subtract the paths, so that the result is then drawn to the canvas.

The exported result appears to be empty of all paths.

```
<path d="" fill="#008000" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"></path>
```

PaperJs docs - http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#subtract-path

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

When you import an SVG node, paperjs try to preserve the document structure of the svg. This means that the top level  tag is imported as a Group object and any  tags inside it will be imported as nested groups.

You will need to get to the paths inside the nested groups to do the subtraction.

For example:

```
function SVGPath(elem){
  let importedSVG = paper.project.importSVG(elem);
  let innerGroup = importedSVG.children[0];
  let actualPath = innerGroup.children[0];
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  return actualPath;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vs3y751m/1/

Also, note that path2, is almost a straight-line with a lot of points in between, but subtraction (also union etc.) only works for paths with an area. So in this case path1 - path2 will just be path1 (similar to arithmetic where a - 0 = a).

[subtraction demo](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)